# IPN simulator cannot reach my handler url

Tags: handler, paypal-ipn

I've implemented a simple POST handler and set it live on a public address. Anyone can post data on it, from any computer and from any tool (cURL, Python, from the API browser etc...) but PayPal IPN simulator gives me this error instead: **IPN Delivery Failed:I/O error: Connection timed out; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out**

I can't see anything in my server logs: nobody is trying to access my handler, while in the other cases (not using the IPN simulator) I get something like this:

```
[02/Aug/2013 15:27:45] "POST /api/1/paypal/ipn/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1359
Key: test_param - Value: test_value
```

Why the simulatore can't reach my handler while everyone else can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Paypal want a secure socket layer for communicate with her, in this case your socket don't receive another communication with your java program, unless you want to create a certificate for your socket.